# How to establish a two-way channel between processes in c++?

Tags: php, c++

I needed to start a PHP process using C++, give it standard input and, after it completes, pick up the standard output.

What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int fd[2][2];
        pipe(fd[0]);
        pipe(fd[1]);
        pid_t pid_fork = fork();
        if (!pid_fork) {
                close(fd[0][1]);
                close(fd[1][0]);
                dup2(fd[0][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(fd[1][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execl("php", "/home/test.php",  NULL);
        } else {
                close(fd[0][0]);
                close(fd[1][1]);
                char buf[1000];
                ssize_t sz;

                write(fd[0][1], "hello, world\n", sizeof("hello, world\n") - 1);
                close(fd[0][1]);
                sz = read(fd[1][0], buf, sizeof(buf));
                if (sz > 0) {
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sz);
                }
        }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo $line;
?>
```

Comment: Do you really have a `/home/test.php`? Does `execl` succeed? Does `fork` return something other than -1 in the else branch?

Comment: Please edit question, add tag [tag:C] and remove [tag:C++].

Comment: You don't say what happens when you run it, but I bet the php script doesn't run. Try `execlp("php", "php", "/home/test.php",  (char *)NULL);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execl` function will not find `php` because it does not search in path. You will have to either use full path to php, for example:

`execl("/usr/bin/php", "/home/test.php",  NULL);`

or change from execl to execlp

`execlp("php", "/home/test.php",  NULL);`